# Is that possible making sure same ID wont appear twice in 2 tables (Database)

Tags: mysql, database

Is that possible making sure same ID wont appear twice in 2 tables?
For example i've got this colum: `call id`
and I want to make sure it'll count it in both tables
for ex: `calls_to_x` and `calls_to_y`
I want to enter both tables data and to make sure the `call id` colum will increase from both table for ex:

`calls_to_x`:

Call id: 1 parameters: .... time: 01:00:00

Call id: 3 parameters: .... time: 01:30:00

`calls_to_y`:

Call id: 2 parameters: .... time: 01:10:00

Call id: 4 parameters: .... time: 01:34:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what RDBMS you're using.

**For MySQL:**

If you only need unique values (and not sequential), you can use something like an [UUID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) to uniquely identify each row.

If you do need the values to be sequential, either merge the tables to one single table by having a field indicating the type of content or use a third table to keep track of used ids with an id field and auto_increment for that column. A second column can keep track of which table used the id if needed. You can INSERT INTO that table in an SQL function and return the value of LAST_INSERT_ID() to get the next id for your other tables.

**For most other RDBMSes**

Use a [sequence (CREATE SEQUENCE)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createsequence.html).

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to have a table that is AllCalls that has a callid and at recipient then include this id as a foreign key in either of the two tables. Only the fields that are different could be in the calls_to_x and calls_to_y table things that are generally applicable to any call could all be in the AllCalls table.

Comment: another variant of this is to have an AllCalls table that has the callId column with a 'unique' constraint, and triggers on the other two tables that insert into AllCalls on insert to those tables. In most databases (YMMV), the trigger will fail on a duplicate id, and roll back the insert on the main table.